# Batch script doesn't work properly if there are spaces in parent folder names

Tags: windows, batch

I noticed that my batch script doesn't work properly if there are any spaces in folder names:

C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\abc\def\example.bat → all tasks are done correctly

C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\def\example.bat → wrong behaviour

**What changes must occur?**

```
@echo off

for %%F in ("%~dp0..\*.wgm") do (
set "file=%%~nxF"
move "%%F" "%cd%" >nul
goto :next
)
:next
if not exist %cd%\output md output
if not exist %cd%\temp md temp

echo File "%file%" was moved from "%~dp0..\" to "%cd%" && move "*.wgm" "%cd%\"

for /d %%i in ("%cd%\") do ( cd "%%i" ) && for %%i in (*.wgm) do tool.exe *.wgm "%%~ni".dat "643054977005802"

move "%cd%\*.wgm" temp\
move "%cd%\*.dat" output\

if exist %~dp0..\*.wgm call example.bat
if not exist %~dp0..\*.wgm goto :last

:last
for /r %%x in (*.dat) do ren "%%x" *.wgm
move "%cd%\temp\*.wgm" %~dp0..\ && rmdir /s /q "%cd%\temp"

exit
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the path & file in double quotes when calling?  "C:\Program Files (x86)\abc\def\example.bat"

Comment: Your script is too complex to analyse just by inspection. You'll need to copy the error messages into your question, and run with `echo on`, so as to clarify which commands are generating the errors. It is also unclear which variables are set to `...\example.bat`.

Comment: Since the script is comprised of several commands, you should point out the ones that are not executed correctly, explaining their intended behaviour and comparing it to the observed behaviour.

Comment: All the `if exist`resp `if not exist` lines have a path not quoted. Remove the `%CD%\` in the first two - they are superfluous.